# Differentiability of $ -f$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

If a function, defined for all $x$, is differentiable on all $x$, $x$ being a real number. Would $-f$ also be differentiable on all $x$ , $x$ being a real number? I can’t think of a counterexample so I think this statement would be true. Can someone correct me if I’m wrong?

Comment: Yes, you have only rotate it around the x-axis.

Comment: $(-f)'=-f'$ so no problem there. In general. $cf(x)$ ($c$ is a constant) will be differentiable

Comment: Do you have a geometric understanding of differentiability and $-f$? If the graph of $f$ is "smooth" (aka differentiable), then mirroring it at the $x$-axis should not make it "non-smooth", right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Consider $cf(x)$ for $c \in \mathbb{R}$. The limit

$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{cf(x+h) -cf(x)}{h}=c\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=cf'(x)$$

exists. Take $c=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

$\ f$ is differentiable at all $\ x$. That means its graph does not have any sharp point and is continous for all $\ x$. So even if we flip the curve about $\ x$ axis which is$\ -f$, it will remain continous at every point and smooth.  Thus it is differentiable too.